# Grouping a list of of entities which has a sublist in c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, group-by, entities

I have a set of Entities which basically has this structure.

```
{Stats Name="<Product name> (en)" TotalResources="10" ..}
    {DayStats Date="2009-12-10" TotalResources="5"}
    {DayStats Date="2009-12-11" TotalResources="5"}
{Stats}
{Stats Name="<Product name> (us)" TotalResources="10" ..}
    {DayStats Date="2009-12-10" TotalResources="5"}
    {DayStats Date="2009-12-11" TotalResources="5"}
{Stats}
...
```

What I want to extract from this set is a new set entities (or entity in the example above) where the first level has been grouped by the  (ignoring the country label) where all/some of the properties has been summmed together, including the the sublist of {DayStas} on a per day basis. So the result set of the example would look something like this:

```
{Stats Name="<Product name>" TotalResources="20" ..}
    {DayStats Date="2009-12-10" TotalResources="10"}
    {DayStats Date="2009-12-11" TotalResources="10"}
{Stats}
...
```

So my question is: Is it possible to do this in a more elegant way in LINQ rather than the vanilla "loop-trhough-each-entity-and-compare"-way?

And I want the set to contain the same type of entities as the original set ({Stats}, {DayStats}), your answer doesn't need to include code for that, I can probably work that out by myself. Just letting you know in case you need to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 dataset.SelectMany(p => new {stat=p, daystats=p.DayStats)
        .GroupBy(c => c.stat.Name.SubString(0, c.stat.Name.Length - 5))
```

Comment: I think you missed the essence of the question. The troublesome part is the summation of the entity properties and the sublist.
But thanks anyway!

Comment: I realised, hope this helps more :)

Comment: A little, but not all the way, atleast to my understanding. I fail to se how this summs the entity properties both on the first level and the second level?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe still useful. RemoveCountry should be an extension method that returns the name of the Stats without the country suffix.

```
IEnumerable<Stats> aggregated =
    from stat in stats
    group stat by stat.Name.RemoveCountry() into grp
    select new Stats
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        TotalResources = (from stat in grp select stat.TotalResources).Sum(),
        DayStats = (from stat in grp
                    from dayStat in stat
                    group dayStat by dayStat.Date into dgrp
                    select new DayStats
                    {
                        Date = dgrp.Key,
                        TotalResources = (from dayStat in dgrp select dayStat.TotalResources).Sum()
                    }).ToList()
    };
```